# How to get data from database and move similar country related button to specific table column using php code?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP coding, i'm developing dashboard to show all my linux servers status. We have lot of servers in 5 countries.

I populated one database table with all servers and their respective countries data.

Now my requirement is, i need to display 5 columns table on my web page and all servers related to same country should print in the same column. For this i have used below code. But it is printing buttons outside the table(for now i populated only Singapore servers in below table).

Please let me know, if you need more detailed information.

```
<?php 
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'instadm','welcome','dashboard');

    if ($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection error: " . $conn-> connect_error);
    }
    $result = $conn-> query("select hostname,ip,status,country from servers");



    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


        echo "<font color='Orange'><b>ENT Zone:</b></font><br>
<table class='style1' height='100' width='1300' border='1' cellspacing='1'> 
<tr align='center' height='10' border='1'>
    <td width=500><font color='black'>Singapore</font></td>
    <td widht =200><font color='white'>China</font></td>
    <td width=200><font color='white'>India</font></td>
    <td width='200'><font color='white'>Indonesia</font></td>
    <td width='200'><font color='white'>Taiwan</font></td>
</tr>
<tr align='center'>
    <td width=500>";
        function singapore_server($country,$status,$caption){
            if($status == 'Y'){
                    echo "<abbr title='$caption'><button class='button' style='background-color:#43D216;padding: 7px 10px;border-radius: 50px;cursor: pointer;border: none;'></button></abbr>&nbsp";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<abbr title='$caption'><button class='button' style='background-color:red;padding: 7px 10px;border-radius: 50px;cursor: pointer;border: none;'></button></abbr>&nbsp";            
                }
        };
    echo "</td>
    <td width =200>
        China
    </td>
    <td width=200>
        India
    </td>
    <td width=200>
        Indonesia
    </td>

    <td width=200>
        Taiwan
    </td> 
</tr>
</table>";          
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $country=$row['country'];
            $status=$row['status'];
            $hostname=$row['hostname'];
            $ip=$row['ip'];
            $caption="$hostname - $ip";             
            if ($country == 'Singapore'){
                singapore_server($country,$status,$caption);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The code in your function won't be echoed in the functions location. It will be echoed in the location you make the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the function at the place you want to `echo`, but it's a the place you call this function that the `echo` is done. You should call the function where you want to `echo` your button (and you could move the function outside the HTML):

```
function singapore_server($country,$status,$caption){
    if($status == 'Y'){
            echo "<abbr title='$caption'><button class='button' style='background-color:#43D216;padding: 7px 10px;border-radius: 50px;cursor: pointer;border: none;'></button></abbr>&nbsp";
        }
        else {
            echo "<abbr title='$caption'><button class='button' style='background-color:red;padding: 7px 10px;border-radius: 50px;cursor: pointer;border: none;'></button></abbr>&nbsp";
        }
};

echo "<font color='Orange'><b>ENT Zone:</b></font><br>
<table class='style1' height='100' width='1300' border='1' cellspacing='1'>
<tr align='center' height='10' border='1'>
    <td width=500><font color='black'>Singapore</font></td>
    <td widht =200><font color='white'>China</font></td>
    <td width=200><font color='white'>India</font></td>
    <td width='200'><font color='white'>Indonesia</font></td>
    <td width='200'><font color='white'>Taiwan</font></td>
</tr>
<tr align='center'>
    <td width=500>";

       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $country=$row['country'];
            $status=$row['status'];
            $hostname=$row['hostname'];
            $ip=$row['ip'];
            $caption="$hostname - $ip";
            if ($country == 'Singapore'){
                singapore_server($country,$status,$caption);
            }
       }

    echo "</td>
    <td width =200>
        China
    </td>
    <td width=200>
        India
    </td>
    <td width=200>
        Indonesia
    </td>

    <td width=200>
        Taiwan
    </td>
</tr>
</table>";
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is bit different. Let me explain again. I have a table with 3 columns(hostname,ip,country) in mariadb. I have multiple servers around 5 countries.Now i’m trying to populate one table on webpage using php code, table format like below. Need to display 5 country names as table headers and all hostnames related to corresponding country should display under the same country header as table data(as a single cell for all hostnames). Can we do this dynamically? Please help me here. I was blocked here.

Comment: Please, don't remove the green tick and ask a new question. If you have a new question, please, ask a new one, and I'll be glad to help you. That's how Stack Overflow works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure. I will post as a new question

Comment: Posted as new question, "How to display mysql table data on web page in dynamic table(nested tables) and similar data should be in same cell". Help me here

Comment: I'll take a look as soon as possible.